# Get SQL to process each row 1 by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, cursor

I have been going around for while trying to get an anwswer to my issue, I think it revolves around cursors in SQL but I am not sure. I think I know how to write the loop for a single row of data but I don't know how to run it for all the records:

Hopefully there is an easy answer:

1. I have a table, let's call it `A`, that has `Product_Code`, `Start_Date`, `End_Date` and `Value`
2. I would need an output table `B` that has column: `Product_Code`, `Month`, `Year`, `Value` when `Month * Year` is in between `Start_Date` and `End_date`

Each record of `A` should then create several record into `B`. Hope that's fairly clear, I'm happy to elaborate if not! :)

Comment: What makes you think you need to "process each row 1 by 1"?

Comment: Instead of word problems, please show table structure, sample data, and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE YearMonth(
    Year int not null,
    Month int not null,
    FirstDay date not null,
    LastDay date not null
);
```

Fill this table with as many years and months that your range of data is covered (no problem if you have too much).
You could do this with a statement like this:

```
WITH y(year) AS (
    SELECT 2007
    union all
    SELECT 2008
    union all
    SELECT 2009
    union all
    SELECT 2010
    union all
    SELECT 2011
    union all
    SELECT 2012
    union all
    SELECT 2013
    union all
    SELECT 2014
    union all
    SELECT 2015
    union all
    SELECT 2016
),
m(month) AS (
    SELECT 1
    union all
    SELECT 2
    union all
    SELECT 3
    union all
    SELECT 4
    union all
    SELECT 5
    union all
    SELECT 6
    union all
    SELECT 7
    union all
    SELECT 8
    union all
    SELECT 9
    union all
    SELECT 10
    union all
    SELECT 11
    union all
    SELECT 12
)
INSERT INTO YearMonth(Year, Month, FirstDay, LastDay)
SELECT y.year
      ,m.month
      ,convert(date, convert(nvarchar(4), y.year) + '.' + convert(nvarchar(2), m.month) + '.01', 102)
      ,DateAdd(day, - 1,
               CASE WHEN m.month = 12 THEN
                    convert(date, convert(nvarchar(4), y.year + 1) + '.01.01', 102)
                    ELSE
                    convert(date, convert(nvarchar(4), y.year) + '.' + convert(nvarchar(2), m.month + 1) + '.01', 102)
               END)
  FROM y CROSS JOIN m
```

The tricky part to calculate the `LastDay` works like this: create a date that is the first of the following month, then subtract one day from it. This handles the problem that the last day of the month can be 28, 29, 30, or 31.

Then just use a join:

```
INSERT INTO B(Product_Code, Month, Year, Value)
SELECT A.Product_Code
      ,YearMonth.Month
      ,YearMonth.Year
      ,A.Value
  FROM A
       JOIN YearMonth ON YearMonth.LastDay <= A.StartDate
                     AND YearMonth.FirstDay <= A.EndDate
```

Depending on the exact interpretation of "Month*Year is in between Start_Date and End_date", you might have to switch one or both of the `<=`s to `<`.